# I get an error when I try to deploy my website with Firebase Hosting - Error: An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

What i have done, 
I ran firebase init in my html/css/js landing page project.
Setup for hosting only, but when i run my firebase deploy --only hosting:sitename I get an unexpected error. Don't know where to start looking.

All my tools are uptodate , firebase tools, node ect...

This is the **Firebase JSON** file

```
{
  "hosting": {
   "public": "public",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
 }
}
```

And here is the **DEBUG LOG**

```
[debug] 
[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:00.434Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:00.435Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:00.435Z] [iam] checking project fakturo-89fe7 for permissions ["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]
[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:00.439Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/fakturo-89fe7:testIamPermissions  

[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:01.631Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:01.636Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/fakturo-89fe7  

[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:02.042Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[info] 
[info] === Deploying to 'fakturo-89fe7'...
[info] 
[info] i  deploying hosting
[info] 
[info] ✔  Deploy complete!
[info] 
[info] Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/fakturo-89fe7/overview
[debug] [2019-02-27T06:34:02.057Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'deploys' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/index.js:88:36
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Comment: What version of the Firebase CLI are you using?  Run `firebase --version`. The latest is 6.4.0.  If you don't have the latest, run `npm install -g firebase-tools`.  If you are at the latest, contact Firebase support directly for help.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I am running the latest version of firebase version , 6.4.0

Comment: Then you should contact Firebase support with the exact steps you take, starting from no project, to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem, I did not update the firebase.json with the newly applied target name.

Comment: @JonatanStorlund how you added the new target name in firebase.json, as I am facing same issue.

Comment: @ajayagrawal the custom target name in the firebase.json has to be the same name as that you used in the .firebaserc file. e.g. "target": "adminapp".  That fixed the issue for me.  Using "firebase target:apply hosting adminapp myprojectid"  does not update the firebase.json file.

Comment: I do not have any "target" field in .firebaserc or firebase.json files. Can someone please write the correct and complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

My hosting is configured for multiple sites, I got the same issue, fixed it by adding

```
"site": "firebase-hosting-site",
```

in

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "firebase-hosting-site",
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```